# search domain in resolv.conf is not appending to hosts when doing ping or other network communciation

Tags: debian, dns, search, resolv.conf

I am trying to find out why multiple search domains do not work with Debian 8.8.0. If you add the search domains in /etc/resolv.conf it will only work with one of them & in this case domain1.local works but domain2.local will not.

If you manually append the FQDN it works fine. This is for any and all CLI based tools: nslookup, ping, iperf, nmap, curl, wget ect. I have seen this before where Debian does not work with .local domains - and you have to remove avahi which I have already done to get the first .local domain working: domain1.local.

I have had multiple .local & other domain's working but with this version of Debian `8.8.x` it is not working.

```
user@host:~$ uname -a
Linux host 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26)     x86_64 GNU/Linux


user@host:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 192.16.1.110
### Standard Search domains:
search domain1.local domain2.local domain3.local domain4.local
```

search domain - domain1 automatically appends the domain1.local and works for nslookup, ping ect.

```
user@host:~$ ping host1
PING host1.domain1.local (192.16.1.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host1.domain1.local (192.16.1.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118    time=63.6 ms

user@host:~$ nslookup host1
Server:     192.16.1.110
Address:    192.16.1.110#53

Name:   host1.domain1.local
Address: 192.16.1.110
```

domain2 will not automatically be appended to the host (hosty) in this example. It will not find hosty with an `nslookup` from the dns server in `/etc/resolv.fon` (although it does exist). However -  if you append the `FQDN` and run an `nslookup`, `ping`, `curl`,`nmap`,`wget` or any other cli based ip communication it works.

```
user@host:~$ nslookup hosty
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.16.1.110, trying next server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.16.1.111, trying next server
Server:     192.16.1.110
Address:    192.16.1.110#53

** server can't find hosty: SERVFAIL

user@host:~$ ping hosty
ping: unknown host hosty
```

**If we append domain2.local on the end of the host it can ping, nslookup, or other.**

**ping,nslookup & curl working with fqdn**

```
user@host:~$ ping hosty.domain2.local
PING hosty.domain2.local (192.16.48.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hosty.domain2.local (192.16.48.20): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=63.6 ms

nslookup with fqdn:

user@host:~$ nslookup hosty.domain2.local
Server:     192.16.1.110
Address:    192.16.1.110#53

Name:   hosty.domain2.local
Address: 192.16.48.20

user@host:~$ curl hosty.domain2.local
curl: (7) Failed to connect to hosty.domain2.local port 80: Connection refused
```

It is worth mentioning that I have this identical configuration on a Ubuntu 16.04 workstation working with around 7 search domains.

The new Debian 8.8.x servers have the issue with working with more than 1 search domain. I must be missing some simple additional configuration that is required for Debian that is slightly different than Ubuntu.

Comment: Try using `nslookup -debug` to see the exact queries that are being tried. The key to the problem may be that you're getting `SERVFAIL` errors rather than `NXDOMAIN`. Also, `dig` is generally a better debugging tool than `nslookup`.

Comment: I did use dig and it does the same thing. If I dig with the FQDN it works. If I debug it is trying to append the domain1.local to the host so that is why it is returning with the serverfail.

Comment: You also need to use the `+search` option to `dig` to make it append search domains.

Comment: Of course it's trying to append `domain1.local`. It tries each domain in order: first it appends `domain1.local`, if that can't be found it appends `domain2.local`, and so on until it gets success. The server should return an `NXDOMAIN` response for `hosty.domain1.local`, then it will try the next domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - so this was pretty oversighted of me but here was the issue. I had the `domain1.local` listed under the `domain` parameter in the `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
### Standard Search domains:
search domain1.local domain2.local
domain domain1.local # removed this line
```

After I ran the debug on nslookup and noticed that it was trying to append `domain1.local` for the nslookup I removed this and clearly it fixed the issue.

```
user@host:~$ nslookup hosty
Server:     192.16.1.110
Address:    192.16.1.110#53

Name:   hosty.domain2.local
Address: 192.16.48.20
```

Pretty stupid of me but just in case someone else makes the same mistake maybe this could help them.

Comment: You sound like this is a known mistake to avoid? I am dealing with the same thing but cannot find anything in the relevant named documentation that one should not do this.

Answer (score 0):

From [resolvconf manual](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/resolvconf/resolvconf.8.en.html), concerning dns-search

The dns-nameservers option is also accepted and, unlike dns-nameserver, can be given multiple arguments, separated by spaces.
The dns-domain option is deprecated in favor of dns-search.

The resulting stanza might look like the following example.

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameserver 192.168.1.254
    dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
    dns-search foo.org bar.com
```

N.B.: *On a machine where resolvconf has just been or is about to be installed and which previously relied on a static /etc/resolv.conf file*,

•
    the nameserver information in that static file, (which is to say the information on nameserver, domain, search and sortlist lines) should be migrated to the appropriate iface stanza(s) in /etc/network/interfaces(5) as just described.

disclaimer: I usually delete network manager, resolvconf and systemd from my Debian servers.

Comment: I attempted this configuration however I like to rely on the /etc/resolv.conf for DNS. It does not work either with dns-nameserver in the ethx's inside of /etc/network/interfaces either. This server has anywhere from 10-15 interfaces doing alot of routing for automation ect for internal networks. The servers do not rely on resolvconf and must  be staticly managed.

Comment: I also always remove resolvconf, avahi, network-manager from any servers.

Comment: # eth4
iface eth4 inet static
  address 172.19.51.252
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  dns-nameservers 192.16.48.20
  dns-search domain2.local # eg - same failed results.